# CoreData in new project

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Hoping you can help.

I've got an iOS app that was built 3 years ago with CoreData. The opportunity arose to make some significant updates and it was deemed easier to simply start a new Xcode project while  continuing to use the existing bundle identifier so that the app remained an actual update for iTune users.

My question is; does creating a new project in Xcode and manually creating a replication of the Model/Entity/Attributes from the first version prevent the data to be available in the new project?

I've got some quick code in the first version of the app that simply returns the number of records in the data (see below), but when the same code is used in the new project it returns nothing, as though there's no data in the app. iCloud was also used in the first version.

I thought that if I had the first version of the app installed, created some records, and then installed the new version, the data would still be available.

Have I misunderstood how migration works with CoreData, and am I better off getting the old project, refactoring for ARC and manually moving over the new code so that the original Entity is still used?

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSString *entityName = @"MyObjects";

NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];

request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"row_id"
                                                                                 ascending:YES
                                                                                  selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];

NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyObjects" withExtension:@"mom"];

NSManagedObjectModel *managedObject = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

NSString *iCloudEnabledAppID = @"com.xxxx.myobjects";
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObject];
NSString *dataFileName = @"MyObjects.sql";

NSString *iCloudDataDirectoryName = @"Data.nosync";
NSURL *iCloud = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];

NSString *iCloudData = [[[iCloud path]
                         stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudDataDirectoryName]
                        stringByAppendingPathComponent:dataFileName];

NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[options setObject:iCloudEnabledAppID            forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey];

[coordinator lock];

[coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                  configuration:nil
                            URL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:iCloudData]
                        options:options
                          error:nil];

[coordinator unlock];

NSManagedObjectContext *moc = nil;
if (coordinator != nil) {
    moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    [moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
}

NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                    managedObjectContext:moc
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                               cacheName:nil];
[fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];

NSLog(@">>>>>> %@", [fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]); // returns 2 records
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm not sure why you tagged this with MagicalRecord. Your sample code is all raw core data.

Second, if I were you, I would take the existing model file from the old app, and make that the first version of the data model in the new app. You *could* recreate the data model with the attributes and entities, etc and eventually end up with the same version hashes, but you don't need to go through that trouble if you've already got the starting point. Just start with the existing data model and move forward. Xcode and Core Data do not tie data model files to Xcode projects, and you don't have any lock in that way. The Managed Object Model files are just text files like all other code in your app.

Third, iCloud setup requires far less code in iOS7. It's pretty simple as the Core Data team decided to take care of all the setup and fallback store busywork. I suggest looking at the "What's new in Core Data" talk from WWDC2013.

And finally, have you made sure that you have actually duplicated the model with the existing store? If you have a model that is not compatible with the store, your Core Data stack will not have a persistent store attached. That is, from the top level (your NSManagedObjectContext) it'll appear to be initialized, but the attached NSPersistentStoreCoordinator will not have any stores. With no store, no data will save, and no data will load. The Managed Object Model version **MUST** match the version information in the store file. You can check this yourself with a calls to:

```
-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator metadataForPersistentStore:]
```

*or*

```
+[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator metadataForPersistentStoreOfType:URL:error:]
```

*in combination with*

```
-[NSManagedObjectModel isConfiguration:compatibleWithStoreMetadata:]
```

You also mention migrations. Unless you have more than one data model, you are not actually migrating your data. But when you do have versions to migrate, you will also need to set the migration options for lightweight migrations (auto migrations) to act when you attach a store to a coordinator. I suggest reading over the [Apple Documentation on Versioning and Migration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html).

Comment: I would add that assuming access to the old project. One may likely be able to get the actual persistent store that was used in the distribution (or at least a close approximation) otherwise the OP will have to rebuild the data even if the plumbing is all correct.

Comment: Thanks for that guys. I tried taking the data model from the old app and placing it into the new app without any luck shortly after posting this post, but didn't have much luck. I'll check to ensure that my persistent store has been duplicated as well.

Apologies for the MagicalRecord tag. I do have MagicalRecord in the project, but in the last few days of attempting to work around it I've cut back on it to try and keep the code "raw", just to eliminate MagicalRecord as the cause. Thanks again.